# KDE looping in GME

Tags: r, kernel-density, gme

I  can not get this for loop to run in GME because i is being changed to 1 and , out is not recognized: wd <- "C:\Users\name\Desktop\KDE\2011\"; for (i in 1:15) { kde(in="C:\Users\name\Desktop\KDE\first15clip.shp"), out=paste(wd, "kde_p", 1, ".img"), bandwidth=1000, cellsize=10, where=paste("PName_ID=", 1)); }

Warning: An unexpected command argument was encountered: , out. The tool will attempt to run anyway, but may not produce the output you intended it to. Please check the results carefully. WHERE clause: PName_ID=1 Error: The command text could not be interpreted. Please check the syntax of the command. Error: An important error has occurred. Please include the information below if you submit a query about this error. Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still confused about this and needs an answer...Refer to page 12 of SpatialEcologyGME http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/images/SpatialEcologyGME.pdf.

Your i was changed to a 1 because the *Output* tab in GME displays the literal statements you tell it to execute. So each iteration of your for loop executes a kde statement with whatever i evaluates to instead of "i."

The main problem I see in this code is that sep='' is not specified in your calls to paste().

Try,

```
    out=paste(wd, "kde_p", i, ".img", sep='')
```

and

```
    where=paste(""PName_ID"=", i)
```

for those KDE input parameters. Use those extra quotes if you're typing these commands directly into the *Command Text* tab in GME.

I highly recommend building your commands in R using cat() and paste() and writing to some text file, which you can then run in GME (File -> Run GME Script).